# Apply MeshBasicMaterial to loaded obj+mtl with Three.js

Tags: three.js

When I load obj+mtl+jpg data with Three.js, the material of the object is set to MeshLambertMaterial according to three.js document. If I want to change the material to another one such as MeshBasicMaterial, how can I do that?

The following code loads obj+mtl+jpg from my server and display the data with MeshLambertMaterial. I tried to apply MeshBasicMaterial with the following code (commented), but it failed and the object with displayed in white.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="canvas_frame"></div>
    <script>
    var canvasFrame, scene, renderer, camera;
    canvasFrame = document.getElementById('canvas_frame');
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    canvasFrame.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set(50,50,50);
    camera.lookAt( {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0} );
    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
    scene.add(ambient);

    function animate() {
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    }

    function loadObjMtl(objUrl, mtlUrl, url, x, y, z){
          var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
          loader.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
          loader.load( objUrl, mtlUrl,
              function ( object ) {
                object.url = url; 
                object.position.set(x,y,z);

            object.traverse( function( node ) {
                if( node.material ) {
                    ////This doesn't work. How can I apply material for loaded obj?
                    //var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
                    //if ( node instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                    //    node.material = material;
                    //}
                }
            });





                scene.add ( object ); 
            });
    }

    objUrl = "http://test2.psychic-vr-lab.com/temp/mesh_reduced.obj";
    mtlUrl = "http://test2.psychic-vr-lab.com/temp/mesh_reduced.mtl";
    loadObjMtl(objUrl,mtlUrl,"",0,0,0);

    animate(); 
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see it totally white because you are not specifying any color for *MeshBasicMaterial*.

Try this:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
```

You'll see all red: it is working.

I think that you probably want to distinguish the different meshes, or apply any texture, do you?

Comment: I maybe misunderstood. What I want to do is applying material which doesn't receive shadow or is not affected by light. What material should I use for it?

Comment: MeshBasic is the right one: actually it is not affected by light and that's why you are seeing only the raw flat color (in your case the default one: white)

Comment: This code apply a texture to the model with MeshBasicMaterial. But do you know how to load mtl with MeshBasicMaterial? 
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('http://test2.psychic-vr-lab.com/temp/tex_0.jpg')});

Comment: as of today you should probably intercept the OBJ parsing (writing or modifying the importer), as far as I know you can modify or replace the material only once the scene has been loaded.

Comment: Do you know where should I modify? I couldn't find the right place to change.

Comment: Mmmm digging into the code you should have a _MeshPhongMaterial_ rather than a Lambert one. Could you check please?

Comment: BTW, have a look to MTLLoader at row 90, it should be pretty straightforward (I don't know OBJ loader, I use just COLLADA... just reading the sources)

Comment: I tried changing every possible code I can think of which is related to material, but I couldn't get expected result...

Comment: I found the place! MTLLoader.js 369:
//this.materials[ materialName ] = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( params );
this.materials[ materialName ] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( params );

Comment: good! But so you must have the _MeshPhongMaterial_  by default rather than the _MeshLambertMaterial_, don't you?

Comment: I think so. That is complicating.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I was looking to do something similar and did it this way:

As of today Three.js r143 , the MTLLoader loads the materials as **MeshPhongMaterial** as seen in

> MTLLoader.js 495: this.materials[ materialName ] = new MeshPhongMaterial( params );

Because I didn't want any reflections from my lighting. So I set the materials to
MeshLambertMaterial ([see the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=materials#api/en/constants/Materials)) by just changing that line to:

> MTLLoader.js 495: this.materials[ materialName ] = new MeshLambertMaterial( params );

And that's it!.
I know this approach will change the way every other model is loaded but in my case that's how I wanted it.

Hope this helps